Can I do a meta-analysis of categorical outcomes by assigning them to ordinal values in single-arm studies?
I have a collection of case reports and single arm cohort studies (without control groups) that describe the clinical response of patients treated with a particular drug. The response is reported descriptively as "complete response," "major response," "partial response," "no response," and "worsening of symptoms."
My questions is :
Can I conduct a meta-analysis by assigning ordinal values (e.g., 1 to
5) to their respective clinical response?
And If yes , what statistical metric or effect size would
the pooled result represent? Can it be interpreted as an odds
ratio between paired dependent samples(before and after treatment) ?
could you please provide me with any specific resources or references related to my inquiry?
